# Why expectation without brackets?

Tags: probability, notation

I am reading a measure-theoretic probability book and am confused by author sometimes using brackets, sometimes not around operand of expectation. The inconsistency could even be in the same expression, e.g.
$$\mathbb EU_{n} \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}((Y_n-a)^{+})}{b-a}$$

Why is he doing that?

Comment: Writing $\mathbb E (Y_n - a)^+$ is a little ambiguous, because which comes first -- the expectation or the superscript $+$? So parentheses are inserted to remove the ambiguity. The author is saying, "were taking the expected value of this whole expression here."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only a notation...

You can find $\mathbb{E}[X]$ or  $\mathbb{E}X$ it doesn't matter.

You can find $\mathbb{P}[A \cap B]$ or $\mathbb{P}[A,B]$ or $\mathbb{P}[AB]$

You can find $log$ when it is a natural log instead of more correct $ln$

...and so on